How to parse a Datetime string without any separator?
I have 2024093013580700 as a datetime string and I have tried to parse it with "yyyyMMddhhmmss":
DateTime.ParseExact("2024093013580700", "yyyyMMddhhmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
DateTime.ParseExact("2024093013580700", "yyyyMMddhhmmsszz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

In both cases I got the following error:

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Any suggestion of how to parse this? It came in from a different source and I have no way of making them change the format.

what method are you using? ParseExact?

Yes. I have tried: DateTime.ParseExact("2024093013580700", "yyyyMMddhhmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) and DateTime.ParseExact("2024093013580700", "yyyyMMddhhmmsszz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

That's because hh uses the 12-hour clock format, but your hour value is 13. Try HH instead.

Nope didn't work. I tried yyyyMMddHHmmss and yyyyMMddHHmmsszz and neither one worked.

You might have too many characters.

The trailing 00 is a problem as well, because that isn't accounted for in your format. What do they represent? If they are 10ths and 100ths of a second respectively, then you can append ff to your format string. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Question was closed right as I was posting an answer: Use the ff format specifier for hundredths.
DateTime.ParseExact("2024093013580700", "yyyyMMddHHmmssff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Wow! Thank you djv and Johnathan Barclay. This code worked: DateTime.ParseExact("2024093013580700", "yyyyMMddHHmmssff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

When you see the Exact in the ParseExact() name, it means it. Anything in the format string that isn't a perfect match for the input data will cause the parse to fail.
In this case, there are two errors:

You need upper-case H values for 24 hour time (hour 13) instead of lower-case
You have characters down to the hundreth of a second, which maps to f characters.

See the reference here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

So you need this:
DateTime.ParseExact("2024093013580700", "yyyyMMddHHmmssff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

And you can see it work here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/l6Evei

